# Cut-Paste copies only one row and not all the rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to match all the cells of the "M" column in Sheet1 and Sheet3, and copy and delete all the rows from Sheet1 that contain any value from Sheet3's "M" column.

Also, I want the records to get copied into "Sheet2" (all records to be deleted).

However, it is deleting all the records but copying only the first row and not all the required rows.

Below is the code:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim lr1 As Long
Dim lr3 As Long
Dim str As Variant
Dim i As Long: i = 1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lr3 = Sheets("Sheet3").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("M2:M" & lr3)

lr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row

For r = lr1 To 2 Step -1

    str = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(r, "M")

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, str) > 0 Then

        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "N")).Cut Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A")
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(r, "A"), Cells(r, "N")).Delete (xlShiftUp)
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Bit hard to tell without seeing your data. Have you stepped through your code to see what's going on? You should add sheet references to all instances of `Cells`.

Comment: If you're using `Cut`, why do you need a `Delete` line?

Comment: @dwirony cut doesn't remove the line, it leaves an empty area

Comment: @Kubie perhaps dwirony was implying keep the delete and drop the cut...

Comment: @SolarMike good point, in that case can change the `cut` to a `range.value = range.value`

Comment: Ah, it's because it's pasting to another worksheet - if it's done on the same sheet, it removes the line.

Answer (score 1):

Well here's your almost exact same code just added `With` blocks and `.`'s because that might've been the problem

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Long
    Dim lr1 As Long
    Dim lr3 As Long
    Dim str As Variant
    Dim i As Long: i = 1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
        lr3 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("M2:M" & lr3)
    End With

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lr1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = lr1 To 2 Step -1
            str = .Cells(r, "M").Value
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, str) > 0 Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "A"), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, "N")).Value = _ 
                    .Range(.Cells(r, "A"), .Cells(r, "N")).Value
                .Range(.Cells(r, "A"), .Cells(r, "N")).Delete (xlShiftUp)
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way to go, but the lack of dots would have caused an error if that were the problem so there must be something else.

Comment: @SJR maybe there was a logical error with getting the last rows or something along those lines?

Comment: Maybe so, think we're all rather in the dark until the OP clarifies.

Comment: Hello @Kubie Thank you for your help! The code is working fine, I can see multiple rows getting copied. But, the sheet "Sheet2" is getting overwritten every time. I want it to get appended with the new data. I tried adding an Offset, but that copied a single row. Any inputs?

Comment: @Siddharth just made a change, how about now? Transferring `Value`'s rather than `cut`

Comment: @Kubie Still seems to be overwriting. New records are getting added from the top, overwriting the existing records.

Comment: @Siddharth  what do you mean adding from the top?

Comment: @Kubie Sorry, my bad. I mean the new records are getting added from the first row. For example, if there were 25 records in "Sheet2" and 15 new records have to be copied, they're getting added from first row to the 15th row. The remaining 10 show the previously existing records. In this example, the new records need to get added from the 26th row.

Comment: @Siddharth  then set i=26 in the beginning

Comment: @Kubie Actually it would have to be dynamic. Because the last populated row would keep changing. Any way we could achieve that?

Comment: @Siddharth  use the find lastrow function for i that u also use for lr1